# App crash each time a new user is sign up in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

The user signs up successfully and it show in Firebase. However, each time the user registers, the app crash although it can register successfully in Firebase. Is there any things I have configured wrongly?

```
 reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email.getText().toString())||TextUtils.isEmpty(password.getText().toString()))
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please fill in all the detail",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else if(password.getError()!=null||email.getError()!=null)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please fill in the detail correctly",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else{
                signUp( );
            }


        }
    });

}

//Sign Up method
private void signUp() {
    String e=email.getText().toString().trim();
    String p=password.getText().toString().trim();
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(e,p).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            Log.d("SIGNIN", "Sign up Successfully" + task.isSuccessful());
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Signed up Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                createNewAccount(task.getResult().getUser());


            }
        }
    });
}
```

**I think problem exists at here**

```
private void createNewAccount(FirebaseUser user) {
    String username = name.getText().toString().trim();
    int point=0;
    String date1="None";
    // Write new user
    writeNewUser(user.getUid(), username, user.getEmail(),point,date1);
    // Go to MainActivity
    startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, RewardGainActivity.class));

}

private void writeNewUser(String userId, String Uname, String eMail, int pointss, String date11) {
        User user=new User(Uname,eMail,pointss,date11);
    mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user);
}

public class User {
   public String uName2;
    public String eMail2;
    public int point2;
    public String Date2;

    public User() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    }
    public User(String uName2, String eMail2, int point2, String Date2) {
        this.uName2=uName2;
        this.eMail2=eMail2;
        this.point2=point2;
        this.Date2=Date2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the crash logcat.

Comment: The app can be install to the phone and open but once the register button is press the app crash. I am using real device to test.

Comment: Can you please post what its displaying in the logcat.